# How to read text content of MS Word files in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, api, contentdocument, ms-word

I know we can search for within a Word content file in Salesforce using SOSL. But reading the `VersionData` field of `ContentVersion` returns a `Blob` which is not `UTF-8` format content, so we could not convert it into a text string within APEX.

I'm looking for any way to achieve the objective of reading a Content file (MS Word) document into a test stream.

Is this is not possible natively within platform, does anyone knows of any REST API services that offer this function?

Comment: .doc or..docx? The latter should be a parseable (more-or-less) XML file.

Comment: *zipped* XML, I mean.

Comment: No it doesn't read them into string. I tried that in apex. We get `Blob is not a valid utf-8 string` when we try to read it in Apex (for Doc/Docx files)

Answer (score 4):

In Apex, it's not a trivial thing to read .doc files. I use javascript libraries to do it. Here is one of the tools that I use:

https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#browser

It does an ok job.

Comment: Sadly, my use case involves strictly an automation supportive approach, without a UI element and javascript is not useful in that approach.

Comment: Got it.... why is business asking for this feature?

Comment: `Process Builder` automation is involved in this approach.